# Android spacing

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I'm having an issue with spacing/laying out views in a linear layout. In the emulator, the layout looks perfect. However, when I test on an actual android tablet, the layout is not correct. See link for an image of what I'm seeing on the tablet.

[Device Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhPCB.jpg)

And this is what I'm seeing on the emulator:

[Emulator Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ugZ.jpg)

I've defined the view in XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sample"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sample"
    android:hint=""
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@={config.sample}"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm really do not know what's causing this code to appear fine in an emulator but jacked up on a device. I suppose I could use defined widths for the Text views but that doesn't feel like the right answer. Basically I need a text view, a space or margin and then the edit text view all evenly spaced even though the text inside of the text views may be of differing lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some changes like

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sample"
        android:hint=""
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@={config.sample}"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So this didn't solve my problem exactly but it did lead me to fooling around with layout_weights and Space views which I ended up being able to use to get everything looking right on both the emulator and the tablet.